# Wordpress loads changed css AND old css

Tags: css, caching, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm really confused what my Wordpress does with css... I have a plugin that is loading a css using this script:

```
wp_enqueue_style('shutter', NGGALLERY_URLPATH .'shutter/shutter-reloaded.css', false, '1.3.2', 'screen');
```

I recently changed the css and now it seem's to be loaded twice. First the older css, then the changed css. On FTP I just see one file. 
Why is it behaving like that und how can I fix it?

It's definitly not a Browsercache problem, I tested it in several browser and cleared the cache several times...

Comment: When you inspect the page can you see both files being loaded?

Comment: yes, there are two files listed, even when I remove the version number in enqeue-style function. When I rename the file there is one file with tha old filename and one with the new filename...

Comment: What is the name of the plugin?

Comment: Have you tried de/activating the plugin? Why don't you just delete the old css file?

Comment: The plugin is the Next-Gen-Gallery plugin, but not the newest version. I can't delete the old css file, because there seems to be just one when I access via ftp. I think the old file is cached somewhere but i can't figure out where...

Comment: is it possible to have a direct link to the problem ?

Comment: it's on this page: http://active-kiteboarding.com/bilder/?album=1&gallery=1 there are two css files, named shutter-reloaded.css used for the effect when you click on a picture

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this css cache issue is always make me mad before. But I find the solution.

I don't know how to put it on your function, but here is the idea:
Give command to your html to call new css everytime you modified the css file, call the css with something like "style.css?1202122354" instead of only "style.css". "1202122354" is last modified datetime on style.css

In my header themes, I ussually use this to call my CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); echo '?' . filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
```

check out the php function`filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css')` is outputting last modified time for style.css

Hope you catch the idea, sorry don't know how to put it on your function :D